# CGDataProviderCopyData leak

Tags: ios, memory-management

So xcode tools tells me that i have a leak in the code below

```
imageRef = [[_originalGridView image] CGImage];
_width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
_height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

//leak?
pixelData = (NSData*)CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef));

rawData = (unsigned char*) [pixelData bytes];
```

problem is it crash's if i try to release pixelData, i am at a bit of a loss here. is there another way to do what i am currently doing with it leaking or am i supposed to release somthing i am not.

EDIT: to all those saying i should release pixel data this is what happens when i try

malloc: *** error for object 0x547b000: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: How and where are you releasing pixelData, because you ***Do*** own it, and it ***is*** leaking a core foundation type.

Comment: No where because if i call release on it anywhere it crashes

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to retain the `rawData` first then you can release pixelData with `CFRelease(pixelData)`
Don't forget to release `rawData` after use.

Comment: I do free rawData somewhere later in the function...But what you are saying is i should retain rawdata Then release pixeldata and then release rawdata? would i not then require two release calls on raw data then? at the minute i use free(rawData); and it does not crash or complain...But the gist of what you are saying is i need to release pixelData Before i release rawdata?

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of CGDataRef data before casting it, then cast to NSData, 
After finishing working with your copy of CGDataRef which you own it, then release the copy Like this.

```
     CFDataRef theData; 
    theData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef));
// caste 
    NSData *data = (__bridge NSData *)theData; 

    //.. do some stuff 

    //Releaase data 

    CFRelease(theData);
```